# De-animate an animated gif with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an animated gif and I want to display it and another set of images side-by-side. Using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373691/2136) I can get the side-by-side aspect done.

However, how do I un-animate the original .gif into individual frames in order to then re-pack them into a new animation? I'd be happy to use a 3rd party library if one existed.

Comment: I think the fact that I have gotten a good, short answer shows that this question is valid and not "too broad"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the individual frames of a gif file and save them as a png using *Python Image Library*

```
from PIL import Image

try:
    im = Image.open('test.gif')
    f=0    
    while True:        
        im.seek(f)
        im.save('test_%02d.png' % f)
        f += 1
except EOFError:
    print "Done!"
except:
    print "Some Other Error"
```